# How to scale video without stretching it?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to scale video `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=720:480 output.avi`. I want to add black background instead of stretching the video.

Comment: Guys i need this. Else my product manager is gonna fire me. There is no sprints in my company only 'i want this feature by this evening'

Comment: I'm sorry for you, but this SE site is not that active and you may not get an answer in time. If you're in a hurry try posting on stackoverflow as they seem to accept ffmpeg questions too and may respond faster. I can't help you since I know too little about ffmpeg. Maybe this question helps you, as it's a bit similar: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21839/adding-blurred-background-to-portrait-videos-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Check out this similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/991371/ffmpeg-scale-and-pad